# QGIS: How to create a crosstab using SAGA toolbox cross calssification and tabulation?

Tags: qgis, dem, saga

I am trying to use Cross classification and tabulation SAGA toolbox. I have a raster DEM file (14 classes) and raster file precipitation (13 classes). I want to do cross-tab - but I don't know how many classes I've to choose (look at the picture below)in SAGA toolbox. And when table is created I don't know which data layer is in rows and which in columns.

[image]